# Cannot convert date string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion

I have a string:

```
string test="September 9th, 2015"
```

I need to convert it to DateTime format so I tried:

```
DateTime dt= Convert.ToDateTime(test);
```

and got an exception (String was not recognized as a valid DateTime). I am thinking it might be due to "th" after the day. Is there an easy way to convert this string to DateTime?

Comment: Probably the solution should also solve the problem with 1st or 2nd, 3rd.

Comment: It is most likely the `th`.  You could try and remove the `st|nd|rd|th` that follows a digit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this function

```
private static DateTime ParseDate(string date)
{
   string[] formats =
        {
            "MMMM d\"st\", yyyy",
            "MMMM d\"nd\", yyyy",
            "MMMM d\"rd\", yyyy",
            "MMMM d\"th\", yyyy"
        };
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
            return dt;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Input");

}
```

Call  using

```
DateTime dt= ParseDate(test);
```

Comment: You could simplify that with the overload that accepts an array of format strings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You probably should throw FormatException instead of InvalidOperationException.

Comment: I think using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` might be preferable to instantiating `new CultureInfo("en-US")` - for performance reasons and for ensuring consistent behavior on different machines.

Comment: @Dai InvariantCulture may perform better, but en-US would be consistent across machines as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try DateTime.ParseExact there you can pass an format string also.

Answer (score 0):

Use this since you are parsing a string not converting it.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "MMMM d\"th\", yyyy")
```

More information can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This will also throw an exception.   A format is needed to parse that string.

Comment: oh didnt see the th, sorry

Comment: You misspelled `ParseExact`, also should update the link.